# Bubble sorting of the users entered prices?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am attempting to bubble sort the prices of each taco (1-10) while having the taco names follow their original prices (the taco names do not need to be sorted). However, I am getting error messages within the if statement of my sorting.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error:
Unresolved compilation problems: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int
Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int
Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int
Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int
Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int
Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int
    at TacoSort.main(TacoSort.java:36)
```

Could I be bubble sorting doubles inaccurately or am I not incorporating the strings appropriately?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class TacoSort 
{
    //Create a constant amount of temperatures
    public static int NUMBER_OF_TACOS = 10;
    public static int NUMBER_OF_PRICES = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the taco price sorter! Enter 10 taco names and prices and I'll sort it!");

        //Populates array of 10 tacos
        //Prompts user to enter name of each taco

        String[] tacos = new String[NUMBER_OF_TACOS];
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_TACOS; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the name of taco " + (i+1) + "\n");
            tacos[i] = keyboard.next();

            //Populates array of 10 prices
            //Prompts user to enter price of each taco
            double[] prices = new double[NUMBER_OF_PRICES];
            //for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_PRICES; j++) //

            System.out.print("Enter taco's price " + (i+1) + "\n");
            prices[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }

        for(double i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PRICES; i++)
        {
            for(double j = i + 1; j < tacos.length; j++)
            {
                if(NUMBER_OF_PRICES[i] > tacos[(int) j])
                {
                    String temp = tacos[i];
                    tacos[i] = tacos[j];
                    tacos[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < tacos.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(tacos[i] + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please print the error messages?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int

 at TacoSort.main(TacoSort.java:36)

Comment: this post is making me hungry

Comment: Each Taco can have 10 prices? check out that new in the first loop. Also this statement `if(NUMBER_OF_PRICES[i] > tacos[(int) j])` - has to be rerwritten. NUMBER_OF_PRICES is set to 10. You should not be indexing into it.. What I would recommend is you start with an array that you initialize with Taco name and prices (i.e. without user input) . Get the bubble sort working and then implement the code where you want the user to enter the data.

Comment: I need it to be greater than or equal to the number of tacos.

Comment: why are you doing this  `for(double i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PRICES; i++)` change the double to an int. also you cant do this `if(NUMBER_OF_PRICES[i] > tacos[(int) j])` the variable `NUMBER_OF_PRICES` is not an **array** its an **int** so you cant call **[]** on it

Comment: can you give a sample input and output so we can see what you are looking for

Comment: Output:Sorted Tacos are
Taco Prices Crispy Potato Soft Taco 0.99
Taco Prices Crunchy Taco 1.19
Taco Prices Soft Taco 1.19
Taco Prices Doritos Locos Taco (Nacho Cheese) 1.49
Taco Prices Crunchy Taco Supreme 1.59
Taco Prices Soft Taco Supreme 1.59
Taco Prices Chicken Soft Taco 1.79
Taco Prices Double Decker Taco 1.89
Taco Prices Doritos Locs Tacos(Fiery) Supreme 1.89
Taco Prices Double Decker Taco Supreme 2.29

Comment: Input:Enter the name of taco 1
Crunchy Taco
Enter taco's price
1.19
Enter the name of taco 2
Crunchy Taco Supreme
Enter taco's price
1.59
Enter the name of taco 3
Soft Taco
Enter taco's price
1.19
Enter the name of taco 4
Soft Taco Supreme
Enter taco's price
1.59
Enter the name of taco 5
Chicken Soft Taco
Enter taco's price
1.79
Enter the name of taco 6
Crispy Potato Soft Taco
Enter taco's price
0.99
Enter the name of taco 7
Double Decker Taco
Enter taco's price
1.89

Answer (score 0):

Please see my inline comments I think they will help you out a bit.
There were a few different issues with your solution which have been noted in my comments. The biggest issue was you were not keeping track of the prices swapping with the name of the tacos since you have two different arrays for both. So if you think about it if you swap taco names it will be associated with a different tacos prices that's not what we want.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class TacoSort {
    //Create a constant amount of temperatures
    public static int NUMBER_OF_TACOS = 5; //<-- you should consider only using one constant value since they will both always be the same
    public static int NUMBER_OF_PRICES = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); //<-- notice i changed replace the scanner with this line to allow spaces in between the name of the tacos
        System.out.println("Welcome to the taco price sorter! Enter 10 taco names and prices and I'll sort it!");

        //Populates array of 10 tacos
        //Prompts user to enter name of each taco

        String[] tacos = new String[NUMBER_OF_TACOS]; //<-- it would be a better practice to create a taco object which would have two values name and price.
        //Populates array of 10 prices
        //Prompts user to enter price of each taco
        double[] prices = new double[NUMBER_OF_PRICES]; //<-- error should initialize this array outside the loop or you will create a new one on every iteration
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_TACOS; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the name of taco " + (i + 1) + "\n");
            tacos[i] = keyboard.readLine(); //<-- you want to read in next line so you can have spaces in your taco names

            System.out.print("Enter taco's price " + (i + 1) + "\n");
            prices[i] = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.readLine());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PRICES; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < NUMBER_OF_PRICES; j++) {
                if (prices[j] < prices[j - 1]) //<-- error here you need to compare prices not what you were doing before by comparing the max size of your array
                {
                    String temp = tacos[j];
                    tacos[j] = tacos[j - 1];
                    tacos[j - 1] = temp; //<-- error here should be swapping element j here

                    /* NOTE YOU NEED TO KEEP TRACK OF THE PRICES SWAP AS WELL */
                    double tempDouble = prices[j];
                    prices[j] = prices[j - 1];
                    prices[j - 1] = tempDouble;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sorted Tacos are");
        for (int i = 0; i < tacos.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Taco Prices " + tacos[i] + " " + prices[i] + " ");
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: It still is not recognizing prices. I cannot run the program due to an errors with pricesdouble tempDouble = prices[j];
                    prices[j] = prices[j - 1];
                    prices[j - 1] = tempDouble;

Comment: there are many bugs in your original code. im assuming you attempted to only copy and paste parts of my code into your solution? this bug is happening because in your original code you put prices inside the for loop. if you see my code i took it out of the for loop and put it after the tacos array

Comment: i've ran the code locally and it is work. I've made several modifications to your code please look at the comments I've added to my code to see the differences

Comment: Okay. I ran your code, but the output is not showing the prices organized with the names.

Comment: @PaulL i printed them line by line not sure it thats what you wanted or all on one line. you can change the print if you were looking for something different. dont forget to mark a accepted answer if this answer solved your question

Comment: @PaulL if you wont all on one line use System.out.print(tacos[i] + " " + prices[i] + " "); other wise use the solution i provided. in my answer

Comment: I will do so. But the names swapped as well. Only the prices should be listed in ascending order with the original name given to the price still the same.. How do I fix this?

Comment: Never mind. I see what you did. Thanks for all of your help! And I will mark this as the the accepted answer.

Comment: One more thing @Marquis Blount.

Comment: This line: System.out.println("Sorted Tacos are");
        for (int i = 0; i < tacos.length; i++) {
         System.out.print("Taco Prices "
           + tacos[i] + " " + prices[i] + " ");

Comment: @PaulL yeah whats that

Comment: It prints:Sorted Tacos are
Taco Prices  fda 1.0 Taco Prices  fdsfda 2.0 Taco Prices  fdsas 4.0 Taco Prices  gfdd 5.0 Taco Prices  gfgd 6.0 Taco Prices  sgfdd 6.0 Taco Prices  fdaf 8.0 Taco Prices  fdfs 22.0 Taco Prices  fsfgd 44.0 Taco Prices  gdfg 76.0 For example & I need it to print in a list form like: Sorted Tacos are
Taco Prices Crispy Potato Soft Taco 0.99
Taco Prices Crunchy Taco 1.19
Taco Prices Soft Taco 1.19
Taco Prices Doritos Locos Taco (Nacho Cheese) 1.49

Comment: that did not comment right. I basically need it in a vertical list from 1 to 10 on the output screen

Comment: at the end of your original question format exactly the output you are looking for word for word what you want. i think i know what you mean but just to be sure

Comment: Sorted Tacos are
Taco Prices Crispy Potato Soft Taco 0.99
Taco Prices Crunchy Taco 1.19
Taco Prices Soft Taco 1.19
Taco Prices Doritos Locos Taco (Nacho Cheese) 1.49
Taco Prices Crunchy Taco Supreme 1.59
Taco Prices Soft Taco Supreme 1.59 (In a vertical list format, "taco price" on each line then the name and price then the next line with "taco price" taco 2 with its price etc etc)

Comment: I'm sure its something simple. but Ive tried using "\n" and it isn't working. It must be more to it

Comment: @PaulL i think this is what you want.

Comment: Yeah. I got it now. Thanks so much again.

Comment: It's saying my reputation is not at 15. I'm sorry.